# How to run method in test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, mocha.js

I simply want to run a method in my test and see if it works.

I tried the following line of code in my testing class:

```
UserPostcodesImport.add_postcodes_from_csv
```

My user_postcodes_import_test.rb:

```
require "test_helper"
require "user_postcodes_import"

class UserPostcodesImportTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  it "works" do
    UserPostcodesImport.add_postcodes_from_csv
  end
end
```

My user_postcodes_import:

```
class UserPostcodesImport
  class << self
    def add_postcodes_from_csv
      puts "it works"
    end
  end
end
```

I expect the console to print "it works" but it prints the error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `add_postcodes_from_csv'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So testing doesn't really work like that.  What you need to do in this case is take a look at the test calls and do something like this

```
test "the truth" do
  assert true
end
```

so you might have

```
class UserPostcodesImportTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  it "works" do
    test_string = UserPostcodesImport.add_postcodes_from_csv
    assert !test_string.blank?
  end
end
```

If you're using rspec, it might look like this:

```
class UserPostcodesImportTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  {subject = UserPostcodesImport}
  it "works" do
    expect (subject.add_postcodes_from_csv).to_not be_nil
  end
end
```

something like that...check rspecs syntax here: https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers

The critical part of that is the `assert`, which is basically what triggers the test to run.  You're asking "when I do THIS, does it return true?"

I'd start by looking here: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html in order to get a better sense of testing best practices.